# Journey History Showing Status as Failed and Detail as JourneyBuilder_EMAILV2_16

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

A new journey was built to send a newsletter to subscribers after opting in from a form on a website. The form creates a lead in Salesforce and then synced over to Marketing Cloud. Using a SQL activity and automation to query for leads with the lead source set on the form to add to a data extension. This DE is set as the entry source for 2 journeys, a thank-you-for-signing-up journey and the newsletter one, with the 1st activity being an email send for both.

I have submitted test leads from the form, see they are in Salesforce and come over into DE and journey after automation is run, and all receive the thank you email from the 1st journey BUT the majority are showing as Hard Errors for the 2nd, newsletter, journey. I checked Journey History and see a status of Failed with a status detail of "JourneyBuilder_EMAILV2_16".

I have checked Journey Settings where Entry is set to "re-entry only after exiting", default email address is coming from attribute on data extension, and for Schedule configuration, we are evaluating new records only - all in file. Verified that the subscribers used in the journey are not set to unsubscribed and on single-send or preview and test, email sends to contact from DE without issue.

[image: Journey History screenshot showing Status as Failed and Status Detail as JourneyBuilder_EMAILV2_16.]

Has anyone encountered this situation with Journey History showing Failed and status detail indicating just "JourneyBuilder_EMAILV2_16" or something similar before? Is there a way to determine what the issue is with the failure?

Comment: Have you checked the email for ampscript / coding errors? Do tests/previews work correctly?

Comment: @NoorAlam Yes, I can do a single send for the email to the same email addresses that show Failed when trying to send to them as part of a journey but they actually do send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally submitted ticket to Salesforce support. Communicated with them and determined that it was an attribute with a picklist of values, and the contacts coming in did not have the same attribute value.

Located attributes under Email Studio > Subscribers > Profile Management. There, I found all attributes and checked each to find a picklist set for 1 that had restricted values set. Recently a value was changed in Salesforce but not in Marketing Cloud so contacts synced over here with new value that did not match the picklist values received this failed message when sending in Journey Builder.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to help any others that might run into this issue as well!